# Arrays and Algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have an algorithm homework about arrays. The question of my homework is as follows.

> Write an algorithm which is determining whether or not some book’s
>    name in the array.

I wrote an algorithm for this question as follows

```
 Algorithm: booksOnTheList

 Names : books’ list
 Searchname : The name to search for 

found <- False 
For each book in the books’ list {
     If ( book = Searchname ) then 
      found <- True 
      }
      print found
```

What are the mistakes and deficiencies I made ? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `print('Found') if Searchname in books_list else print('Not Found')`

Answer (score 0):

let me know if this could help you or not

```
import csv
with open('file_path', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    # because of list of list we are taking inner valid list by index
    total_books_name = list(reader)[0]

books_present = []
books_not_present = []
# suppose we want to filter below list of books
input_book_list =['book_1','book_2']
for book_name in input_book_list:
    if book_name in total_books_name:
        print("book {} already present in list".format(book_name))
        books_present.append(book_name)
    else:
        print("book {} not present in list".format(book_name))
        books_not_present.append(book_name)

print("**** books present in collection %s", str(books_present))
print("**** books not present in collection %s", str(books_not_present))
```

Comment: It is a little confused because I just started learning but thank you very much for your help :)